# c++ casting from base to derived

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm having some trouble to access a derived class' value from base class. My code is:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::endl
#include <iomanip>      // std::setfill, std::setw

#include <vector>

enum EType
{
    E_TYPE_NONE=0,
    E_TYPE_BASE,
    E_TYPE_DERIVED_1,
    E_TYPE_DERIVED_2
};

struct Base
{
    Base() : mEType(E_TYPE_BASE), a(0), b(0), c(0) {}
    virtual ~Base() {}

    virtual Base* Get() {return this;}

    EType mEType;
    unsigned short a;
    unsigned short b;
    unsigned short c;
};

struct Derived1 : public Base
{
    Derived1() : Base()
    {
        mEType = E_TYPE_DERIVED_1;
        a = 1;
        b = 2;
        c = 3;
        d = 4;
    }

    virtual ~Derived1() {}
    virtual Derived1* Get() {return this;}

    unsigned short d;
};

struct Derived2 : public Base
{
    Derived2() : Base()
    {
        mEType = E_TYPE_DERIVED_2;
        a = 5;
        b = 6;
        c = 7;
        e = 8;
    }

    virtual ~Derived2() {}
    virtual Derived2* Get() {return this;}

    unsigned short e;
};

struct Foo
{
    std::vector<Base> mObj;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Foo myCollection;
    Derived1 obj1;
    Derived2 obj2;
    Base obj3;

    myCollection.mObj.push_back(obj1);
    myCollection.mObj.push_back(obj2);
    myCollection.mObj.push_back(obj3);

    //=========================================================================
    std::cout << "base1 = " << myCollection.mObj[0].a << "; " <<
        myCollection.mObj[0].b << "; " <<
        myCollection.mObj[0].c << std::endl;

    Derived1* current1;
    //  this way i got access violation when i try to print current1
    //current1 = dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(myCollection.mObj[0].Get());
    current1 = dynamic_cast<Derived1*>((Derived1*)myCollection.mObj[0].Get());

    std::cout << "derived1 = " << current1->a << "; " <<
        current1->b << "; " <<
        current1->c << "; " <<
        current1->d << std::endl;

    //=========================================================================
    std::cout << "base2 = " << myCollection.mObj[1].a << "; " <<
        myCollection.mObj[1].b << "; " <<
        myCollection.mObj[1].c << std::endl;

    Derived2* current2;
    current2 = (Derived2*)myCollection.mObj[1].Get();

    std::cout << "derived2 = " << current2->a << "; " <<
        current2->b << "; " <<
        current2->c << "; " <<
        current2->e << std::endl;

    //=========================================================================
    std::cout << "base3 = " << myCollection.mObj[2].a << "; " <<
        myCollection.mObj[2].b << "; " <<
        myCollection.mObj[2].c << std::endl;

    //=========================================================================
    std::cout << "ENTER to exit...";
    std::cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
base1 = 1; 2; 3
derived1 = 1; 2; 3; 47472
base2 = 5; 6; 7
derived2 = 5; 6; 7; 47472
base3 = 0; 0; 0
ENTER to exit...
```

and expected result is:

```
base1 = 1; 2; 3
derived1 = 1; 2; 3; 4
base2 = 5; 6; 7
derived2 = 5; 6; 7; 8
base3 = 0; 0; 0
ENTER to exit...
```

Could any one help me to understand:

1. Is there any better way to cast from base to derived, instead of using the Get() method?
2. Why i'm not getting the expected result?

Thanks

Comment: Look at the RTTI and dynamic_cast

Comment: Use `dynamic_cast` if you want a checked conversion or `static_cast` if you already know that something has the right type. Storing a type as enum is redundant, don't do that. Oh, btw, don't use C-style casts, those can easily be the reason your code fails.

Comment: Your objects all get sliced when they're added to your vector.

Comment: `std::vector<Base> mObj;` stores objects, not references.  It's cutting your `Derived` classes into `Base` classes.

EDIT: Brian beat me to it.

Comment: The virtual `Get()` function is entirely unnecessary. A simple address-of operator `&` would have accomplished the same thing.

Comment: There's no reason to cast twice, once with the C style cast and once with the `dynamic_cast`. Just do the `dynamic_cast` and check to see whether the result is null before you do anything with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing isn't inheritance. <strike>You're hiding member functions.</strike> You're calling functions statically on your objects.

<strike>In C++, if you declare a member in a base class as `virtual` and later want to override it you have to preserve its entire signature, **including the return type**. You're changing the return type and redeclaring it as `virtual`, which is all sorts of messed up, but in particular it only works for static calls.</strike> Brian correctly points out that you're allowed to use covariant returns for overriden virtual functions. The rest is still true however.

Which is ok, because you're not even using pointers to store your objects, you're statically storing them as `Base` inside your pointer. You're allocating larger objects (again statically, you have a whole fetish for it), then mashing them together into smaller `Base` objects in the vector, dropping the rest of the data and corrupting your combined `vtable`, you're the calling `Base::Get()` statically on all of them (not the "derived" `Get`s), getting a pointer to the `Base *` object (sort of valid) then lying to the compiler that it's something else, then you're using the memory you lied about.

I'm surprised it doesn't just crash to be honest, you're probably building in debug mode with memory guards enabled (and getting runtime warnings you ignore if it's MSVC).

Comment: Actually C++ supports overriding with covariant return types.

Comment: Oh, I stand corrected. Never seen that used before o.O

Comment: I don't think covariance extends to virtual methods anyway

Comment: No he's completely right, I tried it out with a quick test program: https://ideone.com/GzHncc

Comment: same: http://ideone.com/9w1vKC :P I always thought that was working with non virtual methods only ..

Comment: It makes sense, pointers are pointers, it doesn't really matter what they point to (obligatory 16-bit protected mode mention aside). As long as the types are covariant (easy to check by the compiler), the functional signature is identical.

Comment: @DarioOO That doesn't make any sense, you can't override non-virtual methods.

Comment: Never speaked of overriding infact. Always threated covariance like the misterious thing tha allow to return a most derived type from a method with same name and always avoided that to avoid confusion to end users (if return type is different in my code, also different is method's name)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use struct and public fields, use a class with public methods where required (getters to read values without being able to edit them).

Virtual methods are used so that you can call methods in the derived class by calling them on a pointer/reference to the base class **go back 2 lines and read again.**

Virtual methods works as expected as long as they have the same signature, otherwise you just using 2 different methods

```
virtual Derived1* Get() {return this;} //in derived class1
```

is different from

```
virtual Base* Get() {return this;}
```

but you can do

```
virtual Base* Get() {return static_cast<Base*>(this);} //in derived class1
```

Now you have 2 methods with same signature. That would work

```
Derived1 derived;
Base     base;
Base  *  derivedbase =  derived.Get();
if(derivedbase->Get() == derivedbase)
    cout<<"Nice eh?"<<endl;

using  namespace std;
cout<<derived.d<<endl;
cout<<derived.a<<endl;

cout<<base.a<<endl;
cout<<derivedbase->a<<endl;

//cast to derived
Derived1 *againderived = dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(derivedbase);
cout<<againderived->d<<endl;

//ops that would fail
//Derived2 *wrongcast = dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(derivedbase);
```

Comment: Actually C++ supports overriding with covariant return types.